# How to process more than one item from queue in each run?

Tags: hooks, cron, queue

I have set up a queue using this code.

```php
function custom_logger_cron_queue_info() {
  $queues['custom_logger'] = array(
    'worker callback' => 'custom_logger_import',
    'time' => 60,
  );

  return $queues;
}
```

I add items using this code.

```php
$item = array('uri' => $uri, 'uid' => $uid, 'fid' => $fid);
$queue = DrupalQueue::get('custom_logger');
$queue->createItem($item);
```

It works great, except that when cron runs every minute for this queue (I am using the *Ultimate Cron* module to set this) the `custom_logger_import()` is only processing one item per run.

```php
function custom_logger_import($item) {
  $uri = $item['uri'];
  $uid = $item['uid'];
  $fid = $item['fid'];
  // …
}
```

Is there something I am missing on ensuring that more items are handled? They are only small jobs that complete in less than a couple seconds, but at the moment its taking 3-4 minutes to process just 3 items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The queue system is designed to process items until the time is up. Maybe it's a bug in Ultime Cron? Try running the default core cron.php to verify that.

Are you sure that you're actually adding multiple items to be processed? Check 
your queue table.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it programmatically instead of cron job, then this could be one of the option -

```
$queue_machine_name = 'custom_logger';
$queue = \Drupal::queue($queue_machine_name); 
$queue_worker = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.queue_worker')->createInstance($queue_machine_name);
$item_ids = ['1','2','3'];
foreach ($item_ids as $item){
  $queue_worker->processItem($item_id);  
}
```